# Generating all possible permutations and then combining every possible result?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, combinations, permutation

For example (in python):

```
import itertools
perms = itertools.permutations([1,2])
print list(perms)
```

Will give us:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

But my goal is I need every possible permutation (or combination?) in the form of **-xx-xx-**.
Which needs to contain every possible character from a-z and 0-9.
In which case would look like this for example:

```
-aa-01-
-az-33-
-b6-k0-
-z9-5x-
-aa-aa-
```

(allowing duplicates), etc etc until all possible combinations are exhausted.

I do understand this would lead to a massive amount of possible results, I think -xx-xx- is 1679616 possible results.

My question is, how would I go about this most efficiently? I'm not sure where to begin besides that I've been able to generate a few things using itertools. I'm lost on where I would map each combination to the next until they are all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), with the repeat argument would probably work for you.

Here's a small example:

```
import itertools

for x in itertools.product('abc', repeat=4):
    print x
```

This will print out:

```
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
('a', 'a', 'b', 'c')
   ... clip ....
```

I'll leave the actual solution to you.